# Group By Statement within HQL

Tags: hql, teradata

I'm doing a simple pull from an HQL database. Gives me an error only when I attempt to incorporate the GROUP BY statement

```
select 
element1
,element2
,max(element3) as maxelement3
from HQLdb.HQLtable
group by element1,element2
```

Error message that I receive:

> SELECT Failed. 35: (35) Error from server: error code: '1' error
>   message: 'Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error,
>   return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask

Comment: You'd have to look at the more detailed traceback to be sure of the underlying cause. It could be something like the user doesn't have permission to use the "staging" directory, or running out of memory, or any number of other things.

Comment: your object haven't got a maxelement3 property. So you can create a new constructor with that 3 columns and manage them in that method